# Ito integral over an indicator function

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have very little experience with Ito integral so I am stuck with this task:
For an Ito process $P_t$ starting at $0$ I want to compute the Ito-integral

$
\begin{align}
\int_0^t \mathbb{I}_{ \{ P_s \geq 0 \}} dP_s.
\end{align}
$

Intuitively this should be  $0 $ if $P_t \leq 0$ and $P_t$ if $P_t \geq 0$, but I don't really know how to approach this since the non-continuity of the indicator doesn't allow to use Ito's formula. Or am I missing somethin there?

Comment: A geometric Brownian motion that starts at zero is always zero. Did you want $P$ to be a Brownian motion?

Comment: Sorry, $P_t$ should be an Ito-process. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the comment says, the question makes little sense for a geometric Brownian motion. So let $P$ be just a general Ito process with $P_t = \int_0^t a_s ds + \int_0^t b_s dW_s$.

You want to write the Ito formula for $F(x) = \max(0,x)$ with $F'(x) = \mathbb{I}_{x\ge 0}$:
$$
dF(P_t) = \mathbb{I}_{P_t\ge 0} dP_t + \frac{1}{2} F''(P_t) b_t^2\, dt. 
$$
Now what's $F''(x)$? You are correctly saying it does not exist, but informally $F''(x) = \delta_0(x)$, so
$$
F(P_t) = \int_0^t \mathbb{I}_{P_s\ge 0} dP_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \delta_0(P_s) b^2_s\, ds.
$$

Fortunately, this makes perfect sense via the *Tanaka formula*. The term
$$
\ell_t^0(P) := \int_0^t \delta_0(P_s) b^2_s\, ds
$$
is the so-called *normalized* (or *Meyer–Tanaka*) *local time* af $P$ at $0$ (alternatively, it can be written as $\int_0^t b^2_s \, dL_s^0(P)$, where $L^0_t(P) = \int_0^t \delta_0(P_s)ds$ is the usual "physicist's" local time at $0$).

To sum up,
$$
\int_0^t \mathbb{I}_{P_s\ge 0} dP_s = \max(P_t,0) - \frac{1}{2} \ell_t^0(P).
$$

Comment: Thank you! I did not know the Tanaka formula but now Wikipedia enlightend me. Only for further understadement of the local time: If $b_s$ is some function of $P_s$, i.e. $b_s=f(P_s)$, then $\mathcal{l}_t^0(P) = \int_0^t \delta_0 (P_s) f(0)^2 ds=0$ because $\mathbb{P}(P_s =0)=0$?

Comment: @KennyfromSouthpark, if $b_s = f(P_s)$ and $f(0) = 0$, then $\ell_t^0(P) = 0$, correct. This has nothing to do with $\mathbb{P}(P_s =0) = 0$ though. (The expected local time is actually related to the *density* of $P$ at $0$, not with this probability.)